# Test a map inside a pipe in Angular (Isolated Test)

Tags: angular, dictionary, testing, jasmine, pipe

I have a method that has a pipe with a map inside of it. When I run the test I can't find a way to get into that map.

**This is my component code**

```
public getParents(): void {
    Eif (this.filter.siteId !== null) {
      this.parents$ = this.parentsM().pipe(
        map(items => items.data),
        catchError(error => {
        this.messageService.errorHandler(error);
        return Array<any>();
      }));
    }
  }
```

**This is my Spec.ts code**

```
it("getParents with siteId", async(() => {
      const mockItems:Response = {
      codError: "",
      msgError: "",
      data: "test"}
      let spy = spyOn<any>(component, "parentsM").and.returnValue(scheduled([mockItems], asyncScheduler));
    component.getParents();
    component.parentsM().subscribe(items => {
      expect(items).toEqual(mockItems);
    });
    spy.calls.reset();
  }));
```

**This is my code coverage**

[image: Pipe map test]

Comment: what is `parentsM` in your test file ? Does it return `this.parents$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues here. You actually have to subscribe to `this.parents$` to execute the map, which makes your test async. In your test, you're subscribing on the result of `parentsM()`, which I guess doesn't return exactly `this.parents$`, so you're not subscribing to the pipe you wrote. You may also use `waitForAsync` instead of `async`.

Please try this:

```
it("getParents with siteId", waitForAsync(() => { // <== waitForAsync
      const mockItems:Response = {
      codError: "",
      msgError: "",
      data: "test"}
      let spy = spyOn<any>(component, "parentsM").and.returnValue(scheduled([mockItems], asyncScheduler));
    component.getParents();
    component.parents$.subscribe(items => { // <== parents$
      expect(items).toEqual(mockItems);
    });
    
    spy.calls.reset();
}));
```